# opengl surface on qt window covers widgets

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a qt application, with openGL which is rendering to the screen using
`eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, (EGLNativeWindowType)(qwindow->WId()),AttribList)`

I'm using EGL commands instead of Qt OpenGL widgets because I'm running OpenGL ES 2.0 on a pc using powerVR simulator.

My problem is that the surface takes the entire screen of the window in such a way that I cannot show any other widget on top of the OpenGL surface (it covers them)

Anyone has an idea how to see the openGL in the background with widget over it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your `AttribList` to the question?

Comment: My attribList is empty.

Comment: Okay, that's good. I was going to point out that single buffering may cause something to this effect due to the way layer composition works and what would have to happen in order to simulate that. The default surface is double-buffered though. _Is this something that only affects you running in the simulator or does it behave this way on an actual Android device too?_

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will add information - What I am trying to do is take an existing c++ component that uses openGL ES 2.0 and writing a new platform for it that will run on Mac (and other platforms) using Qt. The existing component is expecting an OpenGL ES 2.0 context. openGL ES 2.0 is not compatible with openGL, and the only way I found to make it work was PowerVR with native EGL commands. I feel like this is more of a Qt issue than an openGL issue, but not sure what is the answer